# what is equivalent with "IN" operator in Aerospike?

Tags: c#, aerospike

I have a set by this structure and data:

```
+--------+-----------+---------+
| MODEL  | COLOR     | OWNER   |
+--------+-----------+---------+
|Benz    | Red       | p1      |
+--------+-----------+---------+
|BMW     | Blue      | P2      |
+--------+-----------+---------+
|Ferrari | YelloW    | P3      |
+--------+-----------+---------+
|Audi    | Blue      + P4      |
--------------------------------
```

now want to search in aerospike for just yellow and blue cars. I search in aerospike documentation in both AQL and Query section but I cannot find any things. I want to simulate this SQL query in aerospike with C# client:

> Select * from cars where color in ('Yellow', 'Red')

Comment: almost identical question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64953192/what-is-equivalent-with-in-operator-in-aerospike

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64953854/using-multiple-logical-operations-like-or-and-not-in-aerospike rather

Comment: how do you think those questions are the same? The first one is exactly the current question and the second is about OR logic operator :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aerospike recently updated Predicate Filters to Expressions.  Currently clients and server will support both but at some point Predicate Filters will be deprecated. Expressions are more intuitive in syntax, achieve the same functionality as Predicate Filters and further extend it.  For C#, this link should show you the code example:  https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-csharp/blob/master/Framework/AerospikeDemo/QueryExp.cs

Answer (score 3):

Color IN (Yellow, Red) would logically be same as Color==Yellow OR Color==Red. You can build such an Expression to filter the query.  See example in response to : [using multiple logical operations like OR,AND,NOT in Aerospike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64953854/using-multiple-logical-operations-like-or-and-not-in-aerospike)

For C# client see: QueryExp.cs in the Csharp client code / Framework/AerospikeDemo

Comment: there is no clear documentation for predExp in aerospike documentation. I check the link that you referred to. but I cannot convert it to C# Client SDK. because there is no build method or something like that. if there is any clearer explanation please share it with me.